# How to enter null or nil value in CoreData for NSDate field

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I am making an ChatApp in which in my chat list i wish recent activity(chat request or message) should be on top.So i save the system time when i get any activity but keeping in mind the if any request has come but if it has no time then i enter the system time otherwise  on every when i hit service the response i got will keep updating the previous record and it will always be on top. But when i remove the record from list i want to enter null or nil for time(NSDate) because when next time the request will come i enter the new time.How it is possible to enter nil value for NSDate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the way i have just entered the empty string for NSDate field to store to CoreData and it accept null.

Comment: Are you saying to delete

Comment: Or you can add what you did to solve the problem,  and accept that as the answer!

Comment: Thanks Hackman for information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to solve this. I just entered the empty string in the NSDate field of CoreData and it interprets it as null value.